# Should I be worried that my site crashes IE9 and how to fix?

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, internet-explorer

I've downloaded the latest version of IE9 beta and my site wrecks it.  No problems on any other browser, but on IE9 it freezes on every page.  The thing is, many other sites also make it gag.

- Should I worry?
- IE's fault or do my site and I need to do some serious soul searching?
- How does one debug this stuff and are there a list of common culprits?  Is it most likely a Javascript issue?  jQuery?

Comment: Don't worry, most sites crash IE :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your site is dying on IE9 (assuming it's not the result of known IE9 bugs), you definitely need to address it. You can download tools like the [IE Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=95e06cbe-4940-4218-b75d-b8856fced535) to help you move about within your page once it's loaded, and there are other resources online like [jslint](http://www.jslint.com/) that will help you examine some of your javascript and work on its quality.

If you find any specific issues that you're unsure of how to address, please don't hesitate to return here and post more questions - there are (literally) thousands upon thousands of brilliant minds waiting to assist you.

*Update* - You mentioned in the comments below that IE9 dies before you can even determine what is causing it to die. This is (unfortunately) the case with much software. Often times you can try to repeat the same actions in Chrome, Firefox, Opera or some other browser and see how it responds. Many times you'll find that another browser may provide an error without crashing entirely. This could give you some insight into what may be causing IE to crash.

Comment: true that!  1000s of brilliant minds!  I've posted many specific questions but with IE9 I don't know where to start.  I have the IE Dev Toolbar, and IE's "DebugBar"...but the site crashes so there is no debug starting point.  But for instance so does msn.com (tested on several computers).  jslint is a great suggestion but I've run it with the "Good Parts" and it checks out (mostly)

Comment: but +1 for the jslint suggestion, I'm going to give the whole site another run through

Comment: @Emile You may also find value in MSFT's IE9 Feedback Program. You can gain access at https://connect.microsoft.com/ where you can also find a list of published bugs and release notes.

Comment: @Emile In light of you comments, I've appended an additional suggestion to my answer above.

Comment: all great links and great suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

Jonathan submitted a great answer about using jslint to verify the integrity of the JavaScript, and using other debug tools on other browsers to detect for a non-crash error.  I did both and thoroughly went through my site, only to find that IE9 was still crashing!

So I looked into it and here's what I found: the main cause of IE9 beta crashes are add-ons that are incompatible with the new release.  Adobe PDF viewers, printer add-ons, toolbars, etc.  Most everyone has at least one add-on in their browsers.  So I disabled all my add-ons and now my site works.

I'm not sure why my site seemed to crash more than others with IE9, but if people are having problems with there site, I'd suggest (1) disabling all add-ons just in case, and then (2) using Jonathan's answer (which I'll leave checked as the official answer since it has to do more with programming).